# Developing microservices in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

We are slowly migrating our tomcat application to microservices, meaning that we need several tomcat applications at once. This is easy in kubernetes cluster, but not easy to achieve in development environment.

We are using IntelliJ Idea and it would be the easiest to be able to run once tomcat instance and deploy all applications to it. This seems to be a problem as Idea runs into `java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)` as it is trying to bind to ports which were bound in other microservice running.

What is the best practice to do these things? How to run several instances without having to run several tomcats on different ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When developing microservices, it should not matter where (on which port) the applications run. I run my microservices (based on spring-boot) locally on different ports with a development profile/config.

Both locally and in production our microservices talk to each other using a message broker like ActiveMQ. This way it doesn't matter on which port they run.

So my advice would be: just run them on different ports and make sure they don't depend on the ports using a service registry.

If you add more details about your setup and applications perhaps we can give you a more detailed answer on how to accomplish it.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. So basically for each service we should choose a different port manually (in IntelliJ Idea there is no way (as far as I know) to pick the port automatically and distribute it to some Messaging service. Then I had to configure this MB manually as well. Is there some more clever concept when developing locally? The setup is simple: Java 9 + Tomcat + Spring.

Comment: Just provide (hardcode) the port in your spring config in a "dev" profile. e.g. 8081 for service A, 8082 for service B etc. We start with 8081 on purpose because 8080 is reserved for the MB.